# Does ASR(DR) supports PAAS over azure

Tags: azure, paas, iaas

Does **ASR(DR)** supports **PAAS** over azure. mostly I see its for **IAAS**,  I dont see any direct information related to this topic.

I am looking for **DR** solution for website hosted on azure Paas

Comment: Refer the below article for available DR options  for Azure applications:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/resiliency/disaster-recovery-azure-applications

Answer (score 1):

To implement DR in Azure PAAS, you need to create another resource and using traffic manager you should include Primary and DR site. If Primary site is down, traffic manager  will redirect requests to DR site.